# String range search over a RAW datatype

Tags: oracle, plsql

We are using an oracle table as a simple event store, in this table we are saving the message ids (.Net GUID using a SequentialGuidComb) as RAW(16).

We are writing a consuming application which needs to query the table using a range eg...

```
select *
from events
where messageid > :from and messageid <= to
```

The problem is when Oracle stores the guids as RAW, it seems to reorders the bytes in the database, so when Oracle tries to do the compare, we are getting incorrect results.

The easy fix is to not use RAW and to change the column to nvarchar but this effectively doubles the storage.

Is there a way to perform this query accurately and still store the GUID as RAW?

Comment: Can you please provide us with insert statement?

Comment: How many rows are you going to have in this table?

Answer (score 0):

you can use hextoraw , for example

```
select *
from events
where messageid > hextoraw(:from) and messageid <= hextoraw(:to)
```

[Docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions056.htm)